# Export to excel with browser localization - ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, localization, export-to-excel

I have gridview and I am exporting to excel that gridview with below code.

```
Response.ClearContent()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; 
                       filename=ExcelShipments_" & DateTime.Now.Ticks & ".xls")
Response.ContentType = "application/excel"
Dim sWriter As New StringWriter()
Dim hTextWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(sWriter)
Dim hForm As New HtmlForm()
ucShipmentList.ShipmentGrid.Parent.Controls.Add(hForm)
hForm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
hForm.Controls.Add(ucShipmentList.ShipmentGrid)

hForm.RenderControl(hTextWriter)

Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()
sBuilder.Append("<html xmlns:v=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"" xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"" xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40""> <head><meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html;charset=windows-1252""><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>ExportToExcel</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head> <body>")
                sBuilder.Append(sWriter.ToString() & "</body></html>")

Response.Write(sBuilder.ToString())
Response.End()
```

I have dutch language in page default set therefore grid displays on page is correct but while doing export to excel, It shows exported in English.
How can I preserve language while exporting to excel?

Comment: any idea anyone can provide input on this one?

Comment: You could try changing charset=windows-1252 to charset=utf-8 and see if that changes anything?

Comment: I tried changing that but still not working.

Comment: I found this article that deals with international issues in excel - it may allude to a solution! http://www.rondebruin.nl/international.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Open XML SDK and create a "real" Excel document.